# Codeigniter - how to pass variable without load view

Tags: codeigniter, variables

I have this data in my controller to load a view:

```
private $data //defined before my construct function

function index(){
    $this->data['myvar'] = 'test'
    $this->load->view('homeview', $this->data);
}
```

But the problem is that I want to access the `$this->myvar` variable in the other view from `homeview` like `maincontentview` (it includes it inside `homeview`). My question is how can I pass a variable to `maincontentview` without loading it (`like $this->load->view('maincontentview', $this->data)`).

Comment: `$this->myvar`, you can access it by `$myvar` only.

Comment: you can use session to access the data.....Just store the data in session and then retrieve it from session in that particular view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

In Controller

```
function index(){
  $data['myvar'] = 'test'
  $this->load->view('homeview', $data);
}
```

In your homeview if you are laoding maincontentview then use below code

```
<?php
  $MyData['myvar'] = $myvar;
  $this->load->view('maincontentview', $MyData);
?>
```

Now you can use $myvar in your maincontentview also

Answer (score 0):

If you load the `maincontentview` view using `$this->load->view()`, any variables already available to the main view will be available to that one as well. You just access it via `$myvar` like you would in `homeview` -- there is no need to repeat the data array.

Answer (score -2):

Declare the `$myvar` as a global variable and access global variable throughout the code.

Comment: Global variables are very very rarely a suitable solution.